# Раздача данных своим рабочим процессам

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Есть служба, которая запускает несколько процессов, которым она будет передавать данные (объекты размером около 10кб). Обратно передавать ничего не надо. Для этого есть несколько технологий:

1. File Mapping
2. Named Pipes
3. WM_COPYDATA

Передача данных будет высокоинтенсивная. Какая технология подойдет лучше по вашему мнению?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это будет достаточно субъективная оценка? В пределах локальной машины все методы покажут примерно одинаковое быстродействие, разница в скорости будет несущественна. Важнее порядок организации. Например - данные идут "всем одно и то же, сразу" или "каждому - свое"? Требуется ли головному приложению понимать, приняты ли данные дочерним процессом? Можно ли передавать данные асинхронно, не дожидаясь окончания обработки дочерним процессом? Ну и так далее

Comment: В пределах локальной машины. Данные идут каждому свое. Головному процессу нужно только следить, что процессы живые. Данные передавать асинхронно

Comment: Всё зависит от объёма данных. Если данных _относительно_ немного, я бы просто определил класс, реализующий защищённый стек (наиболее просто с использованием TCriticalSection) и привязал экземпляры классов к процессам. Но, опять-таки, @kami права, всё зависит от того, насколько велик % общих данных.

Comment: А через сокеты?

Comment: Сокеты не подходят тем, что на них будут антивирусы или брэндмауэры ругаться.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov, Привязал экземпляры классов к процессам это как? Процесс не поток если что и крит. секции бесполезны, если только вы не имеете ввиду мьютексы

Comment: Собственно, в вариантах IPC под Windows в абзацах с наименованием KeyPoint все расписано :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx Я бы (субьективно) взял пайпы или WM_COPYDATA

Comment: А я бы взял TCP/IP. Говорят, что winsock достаточно умный и для локальных соединений (когда клиент и сервер на локалхосте) использует внутреннюю логику прямого копирования данных между буферами, не задействуя IP стек. Так что фаервол тут ничем помешать не сможет. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872557

Comment: @zed Помешает, к сожалению. Как будут копироваться данные - это уже будет после установления соединения (да, действительно будет прямое копирование). А файрволл не дает: 1). открыть слушающий сокет 2) установить подключение к слушающему сокету вне зависимости от их местоположения.

Comment: @kami Да нет же. Почитайте комментарии к вопросу по ссылке выше: *in my experience, Windows Firewall never filters packets going to the local host*. Главное, чтобы локалхост был 127.0.0.1, а не 0.0.0.0 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230691).

Comment: @Artem Прошу прощения, не обратил внимания, что указан процесс, а не поток.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, лучший способ межпроцессорного взаимодействия - сокеты.
Причины:

1. Скорость на уровне с остальными(в пределах одного ПК).
2. Возможность широковещательной передачи никто не отменял.
3. Без доработок возможно создание "сетевой" панели управления.

п.с. `WM_COPYDATA` - даже не стоит рассматривать как способ межпроцесного взаимодействия в нагруженной системе.